# Tomcat7 SESSIONID keep changing after applied redis RedisSessionManager applies

Tags: java, session, tomcat, redis, persistence

I'm using tomcat7 with oracle-java8 in Ubuntu16.04.

And I start 2 different tomcat instances for load balancing, but the default behavior is that the session cannot share between them.

So I turned to the solution using RedisSessionManager in it.

After I add the below lines in the tomcat `conf/context.xml` file (*of course I did added the dependency jars in the lib directory*):

```
<Valve className="com.orangefunction.tomcat.redissessions.RedisSessionHandlerValve" />
<Manager className="com.orangefunction.tomcat.redissessions.RedisSessionManager"
             host="127.0.0.1"
             port="6379"
             database="0"
             password="defuRedis2017"
             maxInactiveInterval="60" />
```

Then start a single tomcat instance.

But after that, the server seemed cannot save session any more, and returned a different **Set-Cookie** header in each request, so the login cannot work any more even with a single tomcat instance.

If I comment out the above lines (in the `context.xml` file), the session works as expected.

So what makes it wrong to working with the `RedisSesssionManager`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the point myself:

The `com.orangefunction.tomcat.redissessions.RedisSessionManager` **DO NOT** support setting a `-1` value for `session-timeout` setting, while the default one do.

In my case, my origin `web.xml` file has the below content:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <max-age>2592000</max-age>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Where the `session-timeout` is set to -1, and it makes the session manager always writing a out-dated session, which causes the problem.

By then I discover that commenting out this part of config will stop the problem, and after some experiments, I found that we just use a large `session-timeout` rather than `-1` will make it working fine:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>518400</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <max-age>2592000</max-age>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Hope it helps for the guys having the same issue.